# Minimizing GET requests using PHP

Tags: php, get

I wrote a function that uses YQL to pull stock info as follows:

```
function quote_func() {
$BASE_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

// Form YQL query and build URI to YQL Web service
$yql_query = "select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('AAPL')";
$yql_query_url = $BASE_URL . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query) . "&format=json&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&callback=";

// Make call with cURL
$session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$json = curl_exec($session);
// Convert JSON to PHP object 
$phpObj =  json_decode($json);

// Confirm that results were returned before parsing
if(!is_null($phpObj->query->results)){
    $quote = $phpObj->query->results->quote;
            return $quote;
}
}
```

I then display the information I want using:

```
<?php echo quote_func()->DATA-I-WANT; ?>
```

I know that this is bad because each time I use the function I'm executing a GET request.

Can someone point me in the right direction at least?

Comment: You need to look into caching techniques.

Comment: What if you save the data in the $_SESSION?

Comment: @SonySantos - it won't be shared between users if it's in $_SESSION

Comment: I'll try caching.  My only concern with caching is that the information that I pull from the GET request will become outdated if cached for too long

Comment: that's the whole point of a cache. It saves bandwith and/or cpu time at the cost of the information becoming stale. It's up to you how much staleness you want or can tolerate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you cache the result. You could store the data in a database but the best place is probably a proper cache like memcached, APC or even just the filesystem.

Here's a dead simple filesystem implementation (untested and just for illustration).

```
$cacheFile = '/tmp/myCache.txt';
$expirePeriod = 1800; // in seconds
if (file_exists($cacheFile) && time() - filemtime() < $expirePeriod) {
   $quoteData = file_get_contents($cacheFile);
} else {
   $quoteData = quote_func();
   file_put_contents($cacheFile, $quoteData);
}
```

Comment: Were you to actually use this approach, it'd probably be best to lock the file to prevent simultaneous writes.  IIRC last time I tested it, writes are atomic up to about 10kB, after which point corruption becomes likely.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot and see how it goes.  I'll post what I eventually settle on in a day or two.  Thanks so much for your help everyone!